# Wordpress as webapp login session

Tags: login, session, ios

Using iOS specific metatags I enabled webapp mode on a WP site.
It works nice, but I'm facing a problem:

Switching between apps breaks the WP session. The webapp loads the splash image again and shows the specified index page instead of the page visited and left earlier and the logged in state is reseted as well.

I've found an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998900/maintain-php-session-in-web-app-on-iphone/14594908#14594908), though it's not WP specific.

Is there a WP way to keep the webapp alive while it is in the background?
Extending WP session with `auth_cookie_expiration` filter could solve the problem?

Comment: +1 but have you already tried it? Or are you asking for someone who tries it for you?

Comment: Btw, did you try that as logged in user? Then the auth cookie should update itself - `$rememberme` credentials are then set according to `wp_signon()`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work and users stay logged in while multitasking (and even after rebooting), if they ever logged in and clicked the remember me checkbox in Safari. Since it works this way without extending the cookie session I didn't add any other wp filter.

Answer (score 1):

To stay logged in WP based webapps on iOS devices you simply have to log in and click the remember me option on your webapp wp-login.php page in Mobile Safari at least once.